# SSH tunnel to private EC2 instance using 2 different keypairs

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

My currently working SSH tunnel into a private EC2 instance's postgreSQL server is:

```
ssh -N -i my-keypair.pem -L 5555:10.1.22.67:5432 ec2-user@14.229.71.224
```

The keypairs were the same for both the bastion jump host and the private instance (`my-keypair.pem`).

However, now we use different keypairs, one for bastion host (`my-keypair.pem`) and another for private instance (`my-different-keypair.pem`). How can I amend the above SSH tunnel command, so that I can still use DBeaver to connect into postgreSQL on the private instance?

Comment: Why not use SSM for tunneling? Then you don't have to worry about ssh keys?